# Can't get Grunt working for Magento 2

Tags: javascript, less, grunt

I can't get Grunt working on Magento 2.  I'm going through the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html) and have run the following commands to set up grunt:

```
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
/usr/bin/grunt -> /usr/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
/usr/lib
└── grunt-cli@1.2.0 

$ sudo npm install
$ sudo npm update
$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
^C

Execution Time (2017-03-20 17:24:18 UTC-0)
Total 2m 47.1s

$ grunt clean:nova
Running "clean:nova" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-03-20 17:27:07 UTC-0)
loading tasks  749ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 97%
clean:nova      14ms  ▇▇▇ 2%
Total 769ms

$
```

`grunt watch` does nothing, it just says `waiting...`. And while `grunt clean` seems to work, I'm not sure how I can verify this.

Of course I edited on of my theme's `less` files...
*app/design/frontend/Holy/nova/web/css/source/_extend.less*

I have magento2 running in a vagrant box on my OSX host.  I've tried running grunt on both the vagrant box & OSX host without success on either.

However, the server side `less` compilation is working, it was before I tried to try `grunt`.  I can see my `less` changes take effect once I clear the cache with:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean; php bin/magento cache:flush; rm -rf pub/static/frontend/Monsoon/nova/en_IE/ ; rm -rf var/view_pre
```

processed/

I'm not sure what the advantage is with using grunt in my workflow if the server compiles the `less` files.  Just trying to get a grip of Magento2.

Comment: I think its working. Grunt will trigger only when you make some changes into your less file. It will automatically appear.

Comment: Have you added your nova theme into `dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` ? Also have write permissions to `var/view_preprocessed`. `grunt `clean:nova` 0 paths cleaned ?

Comment: `grunt clean:nova` should be followed by `grunt exec:nova`. `grunt watch` listens on theme .less file changes and does `grunt less:nova`. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just needed to run `grunt exec` before running `grunt watch` for it to work

```
$ grunt exec:nova
Running "exec:nova" (exec) task
Running "clean:nova" (clean) task
>> 290 paths cleaned.

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-03-20 22:02:04 UTC-0)
loading tasks  1.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 35%
clean:nova     2.2s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 64%
Total 3.4s

Processed Area: frontend, Locale: en_US, Theme: Holy/nova, File type: less.
-> css/styles-m.less
-> css/styles-l.less
Successfully processed.

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-03-20 22:02:02 UTC-0)
loading tasks   1.2s  ▇▇▇▇ 3%
exec:nova      42.4s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 97%
Total 43.6s

$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
>> File "pub/static/frontend/Holy/nova/en_US/css/source/_extend.less" changed.
Running "less:nova" (less) task
File pub/static/frontend/Holy/nova/en_US/css/styles-m.css created: 333.74 kB → 574.1 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Holy/nova/en_US/css/styles-l.css created: 80.3 kB → 138.35 kB

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2017-03-20 22:03:33 UTC-0)
loading tasks                2.9s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 5%
loading grunt-contrib-less  859ms  ▇▇ 1%
less:nova                   58.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 94%
Total 1m 2.2s

Completed in 65.223s at Mon Mar 20 2017 22:04:35 GMT+0000 (UTC) - Waiting...
```

Have to say this workflow is very slow.  I wonder is there anyway to enable source maps for Magento 2's `less` files.

Comment: It does feel really slow if you are making CSS edits. I have heard that pulling the site down to your local machine should speed up the task however I havent had the time to confirm this for myself. 

I find that if I am going to be making a lot of CSS adjustments then I keep a text editor open and use the inspector on the frontend to find the needed adjustments and transfer those statements to the text editor. Once Im happy or find a stopping point I transfer the CSS from the text editor to the required CSS file and run my Grunt dance.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be working.

**grunt clean** will clean (and remove) the old css/less files and **grunt compile** will compile the css to less *and then* **grunt watch** will run in the background - updating your css/less as you make changes and save.

My normal routine is 
grunt exec
static:content-deploy
grunt clean
grunt watch

Comment: does the console not update with a message once it recompiles to show it's working?

Comment: It does updated - If you use grunt exec/ grunt clean / grunt less / grunt compile / grunt watch all update the CLI with a status of the work.